# PHP 7 Mime and PDF validation

Tags: php, pdf, mime

This worked in PHP 5, but now it is not:

```
if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
  $mime = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mime_type = finfo_file($mime, "FILE-PATH");
  if($mime_type == array("application/pdf", "image/jpeg", "image/png"))
    echo "file is pdf";
  else
    echo "file is not pdf";
  finfo_close($mime);
}
```

Comment: is there a question in there? check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: @Jax297 - My question is just why won't it now?  What aspect needs changed?  Your link is seven years old.

Comment: if( in_array($mime_type, array("application/pdf", "image/jpeg", "image/png")))
    echo "file is pdf";
  else
    echo "file is not pdf";

Comment: @Jax297 - Still get "file is not pdf".

Answer (score 0):

You compared a string with an array, here's the right code:

```
if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
  $mime = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  if (in_array(finfo_file($mime, 'FILE-PATH'), array('application/pdf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png')))
    echo 'file is pdf';
  else
    echo 'file is not pdf';
  finfo_close($mime);
}
```

Comment: I keep getting "file is not pdf".  What gives?  Has the mime nomenclature changed recently?

Comment: Just tried on PHP 7.2 and Windows 10, works for me. Try to var_dump() the result of finfo_file(). In case you are on Linux, you might also consider checking your `/etc/mime.types`

Comment: Downgraded back to 5.6.4 and it works like a charm now.